# Complex JavaScript DOM query

Tags: javascript, dom, find

Consider this markup:

```
<div data-something="something">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div data-something="something">
                <div data-something="something"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-something="something"></div>
```

I would like to query (not necessarily but preferably with a single query) all the elements that do not have any children with the "data-something" attribute. In other words, I would like to query all top level elements that do have this attribute. Please note that all this elements are not necessarily immediate descendants of the root element.

So the query should in this case produce two elements. The first one and the last one. Both two children of the first element should be omitted.

The best approach I could think of took about five seconds to process 300 elements which is completely inadequate and I would rather not even show it :)

Comment: It seems that $('[data-something]:not(:has([data-something]))') does the trick, but I'm currently working in Dojo that doesn't support :has (not sure about :not). Any ideas?

Comment: Depending on your markup, you could ask for direct children from your root element. For example, assuming your root is the body:

`body > div[data-something]`

Comment: You could always drop in sizzle with dojo. http://sizzlejs.com/ That will give you all the fancy selectors that jQuery has.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: can you re-read my question please?

Comment: @jeremywoertink: I thought of that the minute I posted my last comment last night because I remembered that I've read in Dojo's documentation, that it's possible :) Will try to implement it today.

Answer (score -1):

Including Sizzle into Dojo worked.